# Wordpress / BuddyPress Permalnks not workng

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, permalinks, buddypress

I'm new a to wordpress and i'm having an issue with permalinks.

I installed buddypress plugin and it needs me to change the permalnks to something other than the default (/%post_id%) n order for it to work.But whenever I change to something ether than the default  get 404 errors. If  switch them back to default the links to pages work but the plugin doesn't.

This is apparently a common and simple issue but all the suggested solutions  came accross did not work for me.

Below is a list of things I have tried:

- Enable mod rewrite
- Change permissions on the .htaccess to 666 so to ensure that it it is writeable.
- Add Options +MultiViews to the .htaccess
- Add Options Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes to the .htaccess

I also read in a couple of posts that  should change  my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default  to

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        # AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        # AllowOverride FileInfo
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

I do not have a default file but have a 000-default.conf and a default-ssl.conf,  added the code above n both of them one at time, at the moment I have it on both but it still does not work.

I have spent over 24 dwelling on this issue but no luck. Does anyone has any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

go to setting->permalinks in dashboard option   and  set the  default permalink and  update  after that refresh site and again set the permalink a per requirement from same option

Comment: Thanks @Vikey but I unexpectedly managed to get it working. It seems like one of the solutions I tried earlier was interfering with the one's I tried after. I deleted some stuff from my .htacess file, restarted apache and then everything was fine again.

Comment: ok no problum  i am only providing  you initial solution without checking the error or site